# How do I add JDBC drivers and configure JDBC Resources in Payara Micro?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, payara, payara-micro

What are my options to set up JDBC drivers and resources when using Java EE Payara Micro?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method combines answers from Mike and Adam Bien via tainos. It involves making a new `domain.xml`, which is a Payara config file. No application modification is needed if it worked with full Payara. The example below is for PostgreSQL JDBC.

1. Open `payara-micro.jar` with an archive manager and extract the file `/microdomain.xml`.
2. Open `microdomain.xml` in a text editor.
3. If your application was already deployed to a full Payara, you can copy-paste the changes below from the full Payara's `domain.xml`.
4. Add right above the line containing `</resources>`, using your dbname, dbuser, dbpassword, hostname:port and poolname:

   ```
   <jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="auto-commit" driver-classname="org.postgresql.Driver" res-type="java.sql.Driver" name="poolname" is-connection-validation-required="true" connection-creation-retry-attempts="3" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="60">
       <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"></property>
       <property name="user" value="dbuser"></property>
       <property name="password" value="dbpassword"></property>
   </jdbc-connection-pool>
   <jdbc-resource pool-name="poolname" jndi-name="jdbc/poolname"></jdbc-resource>
   ```
5. Add right above the line containing `</server>`:

   ```
   <resource-ref ref="jdbc/poolname"></resource-ref>
   ```
6. Save and close the text editor.
7. Start Payara micro from command line, using your paths and filenames. Linux syntax:

   ```
   java -cp "/opt/jdbc/postgresql.jar:/opt/payara/micro.jar" fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro --deploy webapp.war --domainConfig microdomain.xml
   ```

Comment: This is the solution if the database name always remains the same, but that may not always be the case across deployments.

Answer (score 10):

Add the datasource definition to your web.xml and then add the jar file for the JDBC jar into your WEB-INF/lib. Then deploy the war file as usual to Payara Micro.

```
<data-source>
  <name>java:global/ExampleDataSource</name>
  <class-name>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</class-name>
  <server-name>localhost</server-name>
  <port-number>3306</port-number>
  <database-name>mysql</database-name>
  <user>root</user>
  <password>root</password>
  <!-- Example of how to use a Payara specific custom connection pool    setting -->
  <property>
     <name>fish.payara.sql-trace-listeners</name>
     <value>com.sun.gjc.util.SQLTraceLogger</value>
  </property>
</data-source>
```

There is a complete example of how to do this on the Payara Examples GitHub repository. See [Datasource example on Payara GitHub](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/tree/master/Payara-Micro/datasource-example)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure JDBC in a normal domain.xml and supply that to Payara. If you're unsure, you can always take an existing domain.xml and use the JDBC configuration from that.

[Payara Micro has a few command line options](https://github.com/payara/Payara/wiki/Payara-Micro-(Payara-4.1.153)#131-payara-micro-command-line-options), one of which allows you to specify an alternative `domain.xml` file:

```
java -jar payara-micro.jar --deploy myApp.war --domainConfig mydomain.xml
```

If you're bootstrapping Payara Micro programmatically, you would use:

```
setAlternateDomainXML(File alternateDomainXML)
```

Comment: I guess i have to add the JDBC drivers to the classpath before running the micro instance?
Il do some tests, I tried using --rootDir but just caused a bunch of exceptions. 
Thanks @Mike

Answer (score 3):

As [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843059/2854723) didn't work for me a figured a different and slightly easier way. You still rely on the custom `domain.xml`, but the startup command can be simplified:

```
java -jar /opt/payara/payara-micro.jar --deploy webapp.war --domainConfig domain.xml --addJars /opt/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
```

This call doesn't require you to know the Main class.

Answer (score 2):

Adam Bien answered this question in his [19th Airhacks video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYgjP4naC8U).

My take, When used with custom resources is best used as an embedded server, in the main we configure the JDBC resources and with maven dependencies we include the needed drivers inside the jar or war files.

Answer (score 1):

One of options is glassfish-resources.xml

```
<!-- db1 -->
<jdbc-connection-pool
        datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="db1"
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        steady-pool-size="1"
        is-connection-validation-required="true"
        connection-validation-method="meta-data"
        max-pool-size="10">
    <property name="password" value="icoder_pwd"/>
    <property name="user" value="icoder_user"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="icoder_db"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3310"/>
    <property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="db1" jndi-name="jdbc/db1"/>


<!-- db2 -->
<jdbc-connection-pool
        datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="db2"
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        steady-pool-size="1"
        is-connection-validation-required="true"
        connection-validation-method="meta-data"
        max-pool-size="10">
    <property name="password" value="icoder_pwd"/>
    <property name="user" value="icoder_user"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="icoder_db"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3311"/>
    <property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="db2" jndi-name="jdbc/db2"/>


</resources>
```

Complete example with entity manager implementation you can find:
https://github.com/igorzg/payara-micro-jpa-multi-tenancy